# Angular service call to API causes switchmap error

Tags: javascript, angular, api, http, runtime-error

I am using Angular with a Restful C# API on the back end. I am working on creating a simple shopping cart and have been struggling with this all day. When I call the add to cart method in my page, the logic first checks to see if the item is already in the cart. If it is, it increments the count and returns the product so the state can update. If the product is not in the cart, it adds the product to the cart and returns the product object to update the state.

The initial call errors out and it messes up everything - if you can help me figure out what is happening I would be eternally grateful!

C# methods

```
        [HttpGet("GetItem/{cartId}/item/{prodId}")]
        public async Task<ProductViewModel> GetItem(string cartId, int prodId)
        {
            var prod = await _shopCartSvc.GetItem(cartId, prodId);
            return prod;
        }

        [HttpGet("CreateItem/{cartId}/item/{prodId}")]
        public async Task<ProductViewModel> CreateItem(string cartId, int prodId)
        {
            var prod =  await _shopCartSvc.CreateItem(cartId, prodId);
            return prod; // I stop it here to check my return values
        }
```

In the angular forms, I have the following logic in the product card component

```
   addToCart() {
      console.log('addToCart');
      this.cartSvc.addToCart(this.product)
         .subscribe((p : Product) => {
            this.product = p;
            console.log('addToCart.done',p);
         });
   }
```

This calls the cart service addToCart public method

```
   addToCart(product: Product) {
      console.log('cs.addToCart');
      return this.updateItem(product);
   }
```

This in turn calls the private updateItem method to do all the processing

```
   private getItem(cartId: string, productId: number) {
      console.log('getItem-productId', productId);
      return this.http.get(this.getBaseUrl() + 'GetItem/'+ cartId +'/item/' + productId)
         .pipe(
            map((response: Product) => {
               console.log('getItem-done', response);
               return response
            }),
            catchError(this.handleError));
      }

   private createItem(cartId: string, productId: number) {
      console.log('createItem');
      return this.http.get(this.getBaseUrl() + 'CreateItem/'+ cartId + '/item/' + productId)
         .pipe(
            map((response: Product) => {
               console.log('createItem-done', response);
               return response
            }),
            catchError(this.handleError));
   }

   private updateItem(product: Product,  amt: number = 1): Observable<Product> {

      let cartId = this.getOrCreateCartId();
      return this.getItem(cartId, product.id)
         .switchMap(item => {
            if (item == null) {
               console.log('addItem');
               // Create new item in cart
               this.createItem(cartId, product.id)
                  .subscribe(item => {
                     console.log('addItem.done',item);
                     return of(item);
                  });
            } else {
               let total = item['quantity'] + amt;
               if (total > 0) {
                  // Update qty of existing item in cart
                  item['quantity'] = total;
                  console.log('Cart Id',cartId,', UpdateItemQty to', total);

                  this.http.post(this.getBaseUrl() + 'UpdateItem/'+ cartId, item)
                     .take(1).switchMap( item => {
                        console.log('UpdateItem.done - newQty', item['quantity']);
                        return of(item);
                  });
               } else {
                  // Qty 0 so remove
                  console.log('DELETE');
                  this.http.get(this.getBaseUrl() + 'RemoveItem/'+ cartId + '/item/' + item['id']);
                  return of (product);
               } // end if
            } // end if
         }); // getItem - switchMap

   }
```

What happens during the initial add of the item to the cart is it throws an error BUT the item is still being added. Following the log messages, I get

```
console.js:35 cs.addToCart
console.js:35 getItem-productId 1
console.js:35 getItem-done null
console.js:35 addItem
console.js:35 createItem
console.js:35 Global - Unhandled Error:  TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
....
console.js:35 createItem-done {name: "Beagle", description: "", imageUrl: "Beagle.png", defaultTextColor: "Black", isPremiumProduct: false, …}
console.js:35 addItem.done {name: "Beagle", description: "", imageUrl: "Beagle.png", defaultTextColor: "Black", isPremiumProduct: false, …}
```

I am new to Angular, and I cannot for the life of me figure out what the issue is. I can step into my C# backend and stop it on the return statement to look at the value coming back. It is the right type and the right values. The error happens while I am in the backend, when I continue the stream, it goes to completion but because of the error, my object state does not update. The full error I get is:

```
console.js:35 Global - Unhandled Error:  TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:41)
    at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:11)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/switchMap.js.SwitchMapSubscriber._innerSub (switchMap.js:51)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/switchMap.js.SwitchMapSubscriber._next (switchMap.js:41)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:77)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:41)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:41)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:38)
    at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:84)
    at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:15)
    at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:1534)
    at XMLHttpRequest.wrapped (raven.js:376)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:14051)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:498)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1744)
    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1781)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
            if (item == null) {
               console.log('addItem');
               // Create new item in cart
               this.createItem(cartId, product.id)
                  .subscribe(item => {
                     console.log('addItem.done',item);
                     return of(item);
                  });
            }
```

The item is created because you have an API call and a subscription, but there's no return statement. What's inside a subscription doesn't count. If you want to return a stream and perform some side effect, you should

```
            if (item == null) {
               console.log('addItem');

               // Create new item in cart
               return this.createItem(cartId, product.id)
                  .pipe(tap(item => {
                     console.log('addItem.done',item);
                  }))
            }
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked! I am new to Angular and I have been fighting this problem for 2 days! Thank you!!